# Validation groups on collection field

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony4

Hi Im having such a problem with collection type

```php
->add('attributes', CollectionType::class, [
    'entry_type' => CriteriaForm::class,
    'allow_add' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'constraints' => [
        new Valid(),
    ],
])
```

the CriteriaForm looks like this

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('from', TextType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'constraints' => [
                new Date([
                    'groups' => [
                        'date_type'
                    ]
                ]),
                new Type([
                    'type' => 'integer',
                    'groups' => [
                        'number_type'
                    ],
                ])
            ]
        ])
        ->add('to', TextType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'constraints' => [
                new Date([
                    'groups' => [
                        'date_type'
                    ]
                ]),
                new Type([
                    'type' => 'integer',
                    'groups' => [
                        'number_type'
                    ],
                ])
            ]
        ])
        ->add('formType', TextType::class, [
            'constraints' => [
                new NotNull(),
                new NotBlank(),
            ]
        ])
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver
        ->setDefaults([
            'validation_groups' => function (FormInterface $form) {
                $data = $form->getData();

                if ($data['formType'] === 'date') {
                    return ['Default', 'date_type'];
                }

                return ['Default', 'number_type'];
            },
        ]);
}
```

and validation_groups callback is never executed

Edit:

Controller

```php
$form = $this->formFactory->create(SearchCriteriaForm::class);
$form->submit(json_decode($request->getContent(), true));

if (!$form->isValid()) {
    return new JsonResponse(null, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
}

return new JsonResponse();
```

Edit 2: "Solution"
I had also datamapper option set to form, and I find out that the data are mapped to object before validation, and that was the problem. I got exception from my object so I assumed that validation is not working.

Comment: Could you show me your controller?

Answer (score 1):

First, be sure yoyr request is POST or PUT

Instead of doing this

> $form->submit(json_decode($request->getContent(), true));

Do this:

```
$request->request->replace(json_decode($$request->getContent(), true));
```

And then to force the form to handle the request and then apply validator

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

Now the validation should be triggered.